# Write a program that reads a three-digit number(923), reverses the order of its digits, and outputs a new number(329) in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, input, java.util.scanner

import java.util.Scanner

fun main() {
val scanner = Scanner(System.`in`)
}

I know there is possibility of using String.reversed() but the exercise is part of Integers in action so I need to solve it only with integers.

Comment: Hint: `352 / 100 == 3` because the remainder is thrown away when working with integers rather than floating point numbers.

Comment: Hint 2: `352 % 10 == 2`. This is a division where only the remainder is kept.
You can extract each digit using a combination of `7` and `%`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers. I'm beginner in programming and even these very easy things seem hard to me.

Answer (score 0):

thats pretty easy,

```
    var num = 923
    var reversed = 0

    while (num != 0) {
        val digit = num % 10
        reversed = reversed * 10 + digit
        num /= 10
    }

    println("Reversed Number: $reversed")
```

Comment: I can't see why this was downvoted, without a comment explaining why.  It does what the question asked; it's also pretty clear, simple, efficient, and pretty much what I hope I'd have written!  (In practice, you'd probably put that in a function, of course, and maybe generalise it a bit; but it's probably easier to understand like this.)  The only part of the question it doesn't address is reading the number — but the question already has a Scanner, so that's just a matter of calling `nextInt()` on it.